# Oracle - get latest of the subset of the best results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with exam results which is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
studentid INT,
examid INT,
score INT,
attempt INT,
percentcorrect INT
);
```

Now for every student I need to extract his best exam results (measured by percentcorrect), and if given exam has been accomplished twice with the same best score for given student the record with the latest attempt should be shown. I have done it with double nested queries (first selecting the highest percentcorrect, then max attempt from the resulting set and then the rest of the data), but I'm hoping there`s more efficient way to accomplish this. Any ideas?

EDIT:
My query:

```
SELECT 
    result.score
    , r2.attempt
    , r2.percentcorrect
    , r2.studentid
    , r2.examid
FROM
    tbl result JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            res.studentid
            , res.examid
            , r.percentcorrect
            , MAX(res.attempt) AS attempt
        FROM 
            tbl res JOIN
            (
                SELECT studentid, examid, MAX(percentcorrect) AS percentcorrect
                FROM tbl
                GROUP BY studentid, examid
            ) r ON r.studentid = res.studentid 
            AND r.examid = res.examid
            AND r.percentcorrect = res.percentcorrect
        GROUP BY
            res.studentid
            , res.examid
            , r.percentcorrect
        ORDER BY res.examid
      ) r2
ON r2.studentid = result.studentid
AND r2.examid = result.examid
AND r2.percentcorrect = result.percentcorrect
AND r2.attempt = result.attempt
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO tbl(studentid, examid, percentcorrect, attempt, score)
VALUES(1,1,30,1,10)
INTO tbl(studentid, examid, percentcorrect, attempt, score)
VALUES(1,1,20,2,15)
INTO tbl(studentid, examid, percentcorrect, attempt, score)
VALUES(2,1,80,1,100)
INTO tbl(studentid, examid, percentcorrect, attempt, score)
VALUES(2,1,80,2,90)
INTO tbl(studentid, examid, percentcorrect, attempt, score)
VALUES(3,2,10,1,9)
INTO tbl(studentid, examid, percentcorrect, attempt, score)
VALUES(3,3,15,1,100)
SELECT * FROM DUAL; COMMIT;
```

Comment: Please post your queries and a few rows of sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Analytical `RANK` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) can be used for this:

```
SELECT studentid, examid, score
FROM (
  SELECT
    studentid,
    examid,
    score,
    attempt,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY studentid, examid
      ORDER BY score DESC, attempt DESC) AS ScoreAttemptRank
  FROM tbl
)
WHERE ScoreAttemptRank = 1
```

This query will return the best score with the latest attempt per student / per exam. If you just need each student's best exam score regardless of exam, change `PARTITION BY studentid, examid` to `PARTITION BY studentid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Comman Table Expression (https://forums.oracle.com/thread/921467) and OVER (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) for achieving the result. The below query is w.r.t SQL Server, we have same things in Oracle also. Also for identifying the latest exam result for the same exam i have ExamDate in table

```
;WITH    CTE_StudentResult
          AS ( SELECT   StudentId ,
                        PercentCorrect ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY StudentId ORDER BY percentcorrect DESC, ExamDate DESC ) AS RowNumber
               FROM     tbl
             )
    SELECT  StudentId ,
            PercentCorrect
    FROM    CTE_StudentResult
    WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl
WHERE (studentid, percentcorrect, attempt) IN (
        SELECT   studentid, percentcorrect, MAX (attempt)
        FROM tbl
        WHERE (studentid, percentcorrect) IN (SELECT   studentid,MAX (percentcorrect)FROM tbl GROUP BY studentid)
        GROUP BY studentid, percentcorrect)
```